# Regex Help Needed for adding "Required"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have created regex for TextArea (Which supports the Symbols and New Line) and now I want to add "Required" in it. Means when I am on TextArea and using TAB its focusing on on other field. so i want to add Required in Regex. Here is the regex

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%\s]+$"
```

I want to add Required field in this Regex.

Thanks.

Comment: As is, the expression should match the text `Required`. Please clarify.

Comment: Can you clear this point: do you want to make the field mandatory (ie no empty value allowed) OR do you want to allow "Required" to be typed in the textarea?

Comment: Your regex `^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%\s]+$` already match `Required` text. What is the problem?

Comment: Main problem is its working for javascript for JAVA language I have to use "^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$" and this is not working in Java Script. means in Java i have to replace "\" by "\\" and thats not working in java script.

Comment: At that time i am getting following error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$/: Range out of order in character class

Answer (score 0):

> At that time i am getting following error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$/: Range out of order in character class`

That's because `\\-=` denotes a *range of characters* from `\` to `-`, which is `out of order` since `-` is ordered before `\` in the collating sequence.

> Main problem is its working for javascript for JAVA language I have to
>   use `"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$"` and this is
>   not working in Java Script. means in Java i have to replace "\" by
>   "\\" and thats not working in java script.

In JavaScript you can use the same notation as in Java, only for that you must not use the *literal notation* `/…/`, but rather a string like `"…"`.

```js
console.log(RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$"));
// "…" rather than /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\\-=_:.&€£*%\\s]+$/
```